# Why can’t I execute the file from Ubuntu if I give the path name

Tags: jenkins

Started by user Ashwinkula
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TEST
[TEST] $ /bin/sh -xe / tmp/jenkins14675315559555722689.sh

- /home/ubuntu/big2. sh 7 9
  7tmp/jenkins14675315559555722689.sh: 2: /home/ubuntu/big2.sh: Permission denied
  Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
  Finished:

Comment: You may have to give more context if you want to get an answer. You don't even ask a question in your text, so you should definitely get familiar with [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: In case you're executing a shell step from your Jenkins job invoking `/home/ubuntu/big2.sh`, I would add an `ls -l /home/ubuntu/; whoami;` at the beginning to debug the situation. You'll probably see that the user running the shell step does not have the permissions, or that the file itself isn't executable – in which case a `chmod +x /home/ubuntu/big2.sh` may help, provided that you have the permissions to do so... In case it's readable and a `bash` script, you could probably invoke it via `bash /home/ubuntu/big2.sh`, but I'll stop guessing now.